# Use PHPMailer as singleton (like as done with PDO)

Tags: php, singleton, phpmailer

To access my database, I create a singleton object, and access it like `db::db->query($sql);`  Kind of nice!

```
class db {
    private static $instance = NULL;
    private function __construct() {}   //Make private
    private function __clone(){}   //Make private
    public static function db() //Get instance of DB
    {
        if (!self::$instance)
        {
            self::$instance = new PDO("mysql:host=xxx;dbname=xxx", 'xxx', 'xxx');
            self::$instance-> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

Could I and should I take that same approach with PHPMailer?  It seems to work with the exception of setting the bcc property which results in an "attempt to access a private property" error.

```
class email{
    public $bcc;
    private static $instance = NULL;
    private function __construct() {}   //Make private
    private function __clone(){}   //Make private
    public static function email() //Get instance of email
    {
        if (!self::$instance)
        {
            require_once ('PHPMailer_v5.1/class.phpmailer.php');
            self::$instance = new PHPMailer();
            self::$instance->IsSMTP();
            self::$instance->SMTPAuth   = true;
            self::$instance->SMTPSecure = "tls";  //Or SSL?
            self::$instance->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";
            self::$instance->Port       = 587;    //Maybe 465 instead? SSL only?
            self::$instance->Username   = "xxx";
            self::$instance->Password   = "xxx";
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}

$mail           = email::email();
$mail->AddReplyTo('email@email.com','name');
$mail->SetFrom('email@email.com','name');
$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!";
$mail->bcc      = 'doesntwork@gmail.com';
$mail->FromName = $users_name;
$mail->Subject  = $subject;
$mail->WordWrap = 50; // set word wrap
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what the point would be?

Different from the database connection, there are no persistent connections in the mail class, so there will be no performance gains. I see only downsides to using a Singleton for this - not least that you will have to reset *every* property of the class to avoid accidental changes that might have taken place the last time you sent a message.

I would just use PHPMailer the way it's designed to be used.

Comment: Thanks Pekka.  I appreciate your direct response.  I was planning on doing so to just preserver the email password, but agree with your position.  You okay with extending PHPMailer with just my name and the email password such as done at http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=extending

Comment: @user sure, that sounds reasonable!